# Open-source CMS which can define user permissions to read sections of a page

Tags: open-source, content-management-system

Is there an open-source CMS (or even just a wiki) which allows user read permissions to be defined for a part of a page rather than an entire page?

I have a use case requiring that certain sections of the page not be visible for certain users and I'm having real trouble Googling this as obviously different CMSes tend to use slightly different terms.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal you can build a page out of sections which represent (so to say) single content blocks and can separately provided. I'm not sure if the standard module set provides exactly what you want, but it would be possible with small modifications.

Drupal: http://drupal.org/

CMS Made Simple has a "Frontend-Users" module which can display whole pages user-dependent. But if you add smarty-tags like {if $loggedIn}secured content{endif} (pseudocode) to the related templates you can create the functionality to say: open section / secured section / open section / secured section / open section / secured section / open section / secured section on one page / template.

CMSms: http://www.cmsmadesimple.org/

I'm sure that Joomla and Typo3 can do such things in similar or other ways, but here I have no experience.